# Define whether this equality is true?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$\tanh(\alpha\cdot\int_{0}^\infty(\frac{x_1^2}{e^{-2t}}+\frac{e^{-2t}}{x_1^2})dt)$ is nearly equal to $1$, which means that $\alpha\cdot\int_{0}^\infty(\frac{x_1^2}{e^{-2t}}+\frac{e^{-2t}}{x_1^2})dt$ is large enough.

From the image of the function $\tanh(x)$ we know that approximately when $x$ is larger than 4, then $\tanh(x)$ is nearly equal to $1$.

[image]

Thus it is enough to prove that

$\alpha\int_{0}^\infty(\frac{x_1^2}{e^{-2t}}+\frac{e^{-2t}}{x_1^2})dt>4$.

I have the following calculation and hope someone could help me to do a proof-reading of it:

Since $\frac{\frac{x_1^2}{e^{-2t}}+\frac{e^{-2t}}{x_1^2}}{2}\geq 1$ (according to [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)), we have $\alpha\int_{0}^\infty(\frac{x_1^2}{e^{-2t}}+\frac{e^{-2t}}{x_1^2})dt\geq a\int_{0}^\infty 2 dt>\infty$.

Thus
$\tanh
(\alpha\int_{0}^\infty(\frac{x_1^2}{e^{-2t}}+\frac{e^{-2t}}{x_1^2})dt)$ is nearly $1$.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What inequality?

Comment: @BernardMasse Equality, sorry!

Comment: Doesn't make sense in at least two ways: The integral is divergent and tanh(x) < 1 for finite real x.

Comment: @martycohen The infinite integral does not must to be divergent. For the second statement, I just edit the question. I meant the $tanh(x)$ is nearly $1$. Thanks!